# home wireless network by bluetooth

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, bluetooth, windows-2000

Does anyone know if is possible to create a home wireless network by a usb bluetooth port between two pcs?
(By the way I have a windows 2000 as operative system running in one of them and windows xp in the other pc)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The stock Windows XP Bluetooth driver supports PAN, but you may need a third-party driver for Windows 2000.

Comment: PAN (Personal Area Network)