# Home wireless network by bluetooth. Looking for a windows 2000 bluetooth driver

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, download, bluetooth, windows-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [home wireless network by bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/221855/home-wireless-network-by-bluetooth)

Does anyone knows where I can download a windows 2000 bluetooth driver?

Comment: good luck with that one sir....

Comment: I don;t think that they make one, but what is the make and model of the bluetooth?

Comment: @aking1012: It isn´t. This is other other cuestion more focused on a topic, even is related with the question I asked before.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a [link](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php) that could help you even though I have never heard of a bluetooth driver for Windows 2000.